# Could not build module Foundation with Objective-C class in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm attempting to compile a Swift app with supplementary Objective-C files loaded via the bridging header. However, it gets as far as the first line:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

and shows the error:

```
Could not build the module 'Foundation'
```

I've checked that the Foundation framework is included but no luck. I've tried various combinations of deployment targets, architectures, etc too. Has anyone else experienced this in Xcode 6 beta 5?

Comment: Maybe try this: go to Build settings -> Architecture -> Architectures and change the option to standard architecture.

Comment: Can't you just import Foundation directly into your swift file by saying "import Foundation" at the top of the file?

Comment: I should probably mention that I haven't even attempted to declare any classes yet, I'm just trying to build the project with the third party Objective-C library. Importing Foundation in Swift / changing the architecture hasn't resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Doc says

> Any Objective-C framework (or C library) that’s accessible as a module
>   can be imported directly into Swift. This includes all of the
>   Objective-C system frameworks—such as Foundation, UIKit, and SpriteKit

so you could just do

```
import Foundation
```

Comment: No such luck unfortunately. I'm getting these errors whilst attempting to compile the third-party Objective-C libraries. I haven't instantiated them at all yet.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import Obj-C-Headers in C-Files.
(If you are using c in your project).