# What is it means "could not build Objective-C module 'Foundation' "?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a sample xcode project in xcode8.2.1 and I pressed Cmd+B.
  It is showingerrors like this **Expected identifier or '(' in NSError.h** and **Could not build Objective-C module 'Foundation'**

[image]

I am using the swift language with legacy version **yes** in build settings.

Comment: Didn't you make a change in the readonly header files?

Answer (score -1):

Doc says

> Any Objective-C framework (or C library) that’s accessible as a module
>   can be imported directly into Swift. This includes all of the
>   Objective-C system frameworks—such as Foundation, UIKit, and SpriteKit

so you could just do

```
import Foundation
```

[Could not build module Foundation with Objective-C class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344736/could-not-build-module-foundation-with-objective-c-class-in-swift)

*I Hope I can help*